# QML Svg in qt 5.15 static build, using CMake

Tags: qt, svg, cmake

I would like to migrate from 5.9 to 5.15 and I don't get to load svg from QML.
The original version, using qt provided by Ubuntu (5.9) did load svg from QML with
no extra steps. The new build uses a static Qt.

I use:

- Ubuntu 18
- In the house static build of Qt 5.15
- CMake (3.18)

**build Qt**

```
 ./configure \
    -confirm-license \
    -release \
    -static \
    -no-pch \
    -nomake tests \
    -nomake examples \
    -nomake tools \
    -nomake examples \
    -nomake tests \
    -skip qtdoc \
    -skip wayland \
    -skip qtwebengine \
    --prefix=/opt/Qt-5.15.0
```

**CMake**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(test VERSION 0.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

find_package(Qt5 5.15 
    PATHS /opt/Qt-5.15.0
    COMPONENTS
        Core
        Widgets
        Qml
        Svg
        Quick
        QuickControls2
        Charts
        Multimedia
        LinguistTools
        QmlImportScanner 
        Xml
    REQUIRED QUIET
)

add_executable(test_qt

    # c++ code files
    main.cpp

    # qml code files
    qml/Main.qml

    # resource files
    qml/resources.qrc
)

target_include_directories(test_qt PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})

target_link_libraries(test_qt 
    PRIVATE
        Qt5::Widgets
        Qt5::Qml
        Qt5::Quick
        Qt5::QuickControls2
        Qt5::Svg
        Qt5::Xml
        Qt5::Gui
)

qt_import_qml_plugins(test_qt
    INCLUDE 
        Qt5::QtQuick2Plugin
        Qt5::QSvgPlugin
        Qt5::QtQuickControls2Plugin
)
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QObject>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlComponent>
#include <QQmlContext>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int status = 0;

    try {

        QGuiApplication       app(argc, argv);
        QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

        engine.load(QUrl("qrc:/Main.qml"));

        QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::quit, &QGuiApplication::quit);

        if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
            return -1;

        status = app.exec();

    } catch (std::exception &) {
        return -1;
    }

    return status;
}
```

**Main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 850
    height: 850
    visible: true
    color: "lightgray"

    Image{
        source: "image.svg"
    }
}
```

I omit the resource file, but it lists qml, png and svg files.
When using PNG image is loaded successfully, but when using SVG the following error appears:
`qrc:/Main.qml:13:5: QML Image: Error decoding: qrc:/image.svg: Unsupported image format`

The current Qt build contains the following files related to SVG handling:

```
./lib/libQt5Svg.a
./lib/libQt5Svg.la
./lib/cmake/Qt5Svg
./lib/cmake/Qt5Svg/Qt5SvgConfigVersion.cmake
./lib/cmake/Qt5Svg/Qt5SvgConfig.cmake
./lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5Gui_QSvgIconPlugin.cmake
./lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5Gui_QSvgPlugin_Import.cpp
./lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5Gui_QSvgIconPlugin_Import.cpp
./lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5Gui_QSvgPlugin.cmake
./lib/pkgconfig/Qt5Svg.pc
./lib/libQt5Svg.prl
./include/QtSvg
./include/QtSvg/QGraphicsSvgItem
./include/QtSvg/5.15.0/QtSvg
./include/QtSvg/QSvgRenderer
./include/QtSvg/QSvgWidget
./include/QtSvg/QSvgGenerator
./include/QtSvg/QtSvg
./include/QtSvg/QtSvgVersion
./include/QtSvg/QtSvgDepends
```

**EDIT**

I added the missing Svg library dependency to the find_package command. The issue remains unsolved.

If I link against a shared build of the Qt libraries, this project works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was in addition to including Qt5::Svg in find_package and target_link_libraries, eg:

```
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Quick Qml Xml Charts Gui Svg QuickControls2)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Qt5::Core Qt5::Quick Qt5::Qml Qt5::Xml Qt5::Charts Qt5::Gui Qt5::Svg Qt5::QuickControls2)
```

To also include the following when statically linking Qt 5.15:

```
qt5_import_plugins(${PROJECT_NAME} INCLUDE Qt5::QSvgPlugin)
```

That resolved errors such as "QML ButtonIcon: Error decoding: qrc:/resources/images/add-white-36dp.svg: Unsupported image format"

Answer (score 0):

You are using cmake, but in a qmake .pro project,using static linking, you
must add

QT += svg

Note that svg plugin depends of widgets:

"QT += svg"  is the same that "QT += svg widgets"

In android/IOS is better skip svg images to reduce app size.

```
/opt/Qt/5.15.1/gcc_64/lib$ ldd libQt5Svg.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff7bff0000)
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /opt/Qt/5.15.1/gcc_64/lib/./libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007ff0cbf55000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /opt/Qt/5.15.1/gcc_64/lib/./libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007ff0cb624000)
```

You can try to add some C++ QTSVG code  in your main.cpp ,to test linking

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsvggenerator.html

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I specifically ask about CMake solution for this problem.

Comment: yes, but I get this problem with static win32 Qt build. Same error, solved with QT += svg. I think you muts add "Svg" to find_package function :
find_package(Qt5 5.15 
    PATHS /opt/Qt-5.15.0
    COMPONENTS
        Core
        Widgets
        Qml
        Quick
        QuickControls2
        Charts
        Multimedia
        LinguistTools
        QmlImportScanner 
        Xml
        Svg
    REQUIRED QUIET
)

Comment: I updated the code, as you mentioned, Svg was missing in the find_package command.
Nevertheless the program was linking against Qt5::Svg (which means that the library was found and used).

Comment: I think cmake is not generating import plugins code: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.9-devicecreation/qtee-static-linking.html . Try to add to main.cpp #include <QtPlugin> and Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(QSvgIconPlugin);
Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(QSvgPlugin); inside main function

Comment: thanks Miguel, I did try down that road as well. when not declaring the plugins either in the code nor in cmake. The app wont load and will let me know that the plugins are missing. Are you aware if I have to declare plugins both in cmake and in c++?

Comment: maybe you should wait for Qt 6, which supports cmake natively